# Laravel Get rows by time for all dates

Tags: php, database, laravel, date, time

I'm trying to get "Usage Patterns"
So I need to extract from my db all the rows from the last 30 days but only the ones that created at
7:00 - 14:00 for example
the values is from "created_at" so its datetime
I thought just to extract all and check str_contais for 14:00 or something
But I'm sure its not the best idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to combine DATE and TIME queries to get what you need.

```
->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'), [$from_date, $to_date])
->whereBetween(DB::raw('TIME(created_at)'), [$from_time, $to_time])
```

Example SQL

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
    DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2019-09-22' AND '2019-10-22' AND
    TIME(created_at) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '14:00:00'
```